# Combine multiple XML files using XSLT and do some math function

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file **authors.xml** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<authors>
  <author>
    <name>Leonardo da Vinci</name>
    <nationality>Italian</nationality>
  </author>
  <author>
    <name>Pablo Picasso</name>
    <nationality>Spanish</nationality>
  </author>
</authors>
```

and another file listing their artworks **artworks.xml** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<artworks>
  <artwork>
    <title>Mona Lisa</title>
    <author>Leonardo da Vinci</author>
    <date>1497</date>
    <form>painting</form>
  </artwork>
  <artwork>
    <title>Vitruvian Man</title>
    <author>Leonardo da Vinci</author>
    <date>1499</date>
    <form>painting</form>
  </artwork>
  <artwork>
    <title>Absinthe Drinker</title>
    <author>Pablo Picasso</author>
    <date>1479</date>
    <form>painting</form>
  </artwork>
  <artwork>
    <title>Chicago Picasso</title>
    <author>Pablo Picasso</author>
    <date>1950</date>
    <form>sculpture</form>
  </artwork>
</artworks>
```

What I wish to do is combine these 2 XML files into another processed XML file. The XSLT will list down all authors, and within it list all the artworks associated with that particular author and group it by artwork form. The XSLT will also count the number of artwork groups. The duration of the group is also added as an element attribute. This is further illustrated as in the XML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<authors>
  <author>
    <name>Leonardo da Vinci</name>
    <nationality>Italian</nationality>
    <artworks form="painting" duration="1497-1499" quantity="2">
      <artwork date="1497">
        <title>Mona Lisa</title>
      </artwork>
      <artwork date="1499">
        <title>Vitruvian Man</title>
      </artwork>
    </artworks>
  </author>
  <author>
    <name>Pablo Picasso</name>
    <nationality>Spanish</nationality>
    <artworks form="painting" duration="1479-1479" quantity="1">
      <artwork date="1479">
        <title>Absinthe Drinker</title>
      </artwork>
    </artworks>
    <artworks form="sculpture" duration="1950-1950" quantity="1">
      <artwork date="1950">
        <title>Chicago Picasso</title>
      </artwork>
    </artworks>
  </author>
</authors>
```

I am still new to this. What I've managed to do is get all the author part, and now I'm not sure how to extract the data from that other XML file while also counting the occurrence of artworks and so on. I am very experienced in procedural programming such as C or C++, but this method of declarative programming is really turning my head upside down! Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction so that I can get this right.

Comment: You will need to use grouping (see `for-each-group`) to group the artworks per artist. You should also try to work with templates for each node (instead of one root template and nested for-each). It will be simpler and more efficient. Your code is using XSLT 2.0. Be sure that's the version that you support (and tag your question with it), since the XSLT 1.0 grouping strategies are very different.

Comment: updated the tags to include XSLT 2.0. I used `for-each` because everytime I use `for-each-group` nothing is being output!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This stylesheet will generate the output you expect, using the `authors.xml` file as the input source, and having the `artworks.xml` in the same directory:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="artworks" select="doc('artworks.xml')/artworks"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="authors/author">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="nationality"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group 
                select="$artworks/artwork[author=current()/name]"
                group-by="form">

                <artworks form="{form}" 
                    duration="{min(current-group()/date)}-{max(current-group()/date)}" 
                    quantity="{count(current-group())}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </artworks>

            </xsl:for-each-group>  
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="artwork">
        <artwork date="{date}">
            <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
        </artwork>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is an explanation of the code above:

I used a `xsl:variable` to refer to the `artworks` subtree from the imported document:

```
<xsl:variable name="artworks" select="doc('artworks.xml')/artworks"/>
```

This template is an identity transform, which will match any node and atribute and copy it to the output. It has lower precedence than the other two templates so it will only be called if the others aren't matched:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The second template must match `authors/author` (and not `author`, since it is called when processing both documents, and there is another `author` inside `artwork`). The `copy-of` element copies the entire subtree (elements, content and attributes) for the selected nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="authors/author">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="nationality"/>
        ...
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The `for-each-group` iterates on each `artwork` element from the `artworks.xml` file which has the same `name` as the `author` element of the current node from the input document (`authors.xml`). It is being grouped by `form`. You refer to the current group using `current-group()` which you need to calculate the `max` and `min` dates, to count the quantity and to print the `<artwork>` nodes.

```
<xsl:for-each-group 
    select="$artworks/artwork[author=current()/name]"
    group-by="form">

    <artworks form="{form}" 
        duration="{min(current-group()/date)}-{max(current-group()/date)}" 
        quantity="{count(current-group())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </artworks>

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Finally, this template formats each `artwork` node:

```
<xsl:template match="artwork">
    <artwork date="{date}">
        <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
    </artwork>
</xsl:template>
```

You *could* do all this differently, in a single root `/` matching template, and several nested `for-each` blocks, but using templates is a much better practice when coding in XSLT.

Comment: Wow, thanks mate! You have no idea how this has helped me! :)

Comment: Thanks again, was about to ask something, but hey, you put in all explanations as well! :)